# bxslider horizontal effect fade

Tags: javascript, slider, fade

Help to make the slider scrolls blocks but they fade when adding options fade is only one block.

[enter jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/m6wj7/12/)

```
<div class="slider1">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a single slider

http://jsfiddle.net/5znhaabw/

```js
onSlideNext: function (eSlide, iIndPrev, iIndCur) {
  var eSlideCur = eSlide.children(),
      eSlidePrev = eSlide.prev().children();

  if (iIndCur == 0) {
    eSlidePrev = eSlide.siblings().last().prev().children();
    eSlideCur = eSlide.siblings().last().children().add(eSlide.children());
  };
  eSlideCur.stop().css('opacity', 0).delay(350).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
  eSlidePrev.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
},
  onSlidePrev: function (eSlide, iIndPrev, iIndCur) {
    var eSlideCur = eSlide.children(),
        eSlidePrev = eSlide.next().children();

    if (iIndCur == eSlide.siblings().andSelf().length - 2 - 1) {
      eSlidePrev = eSlide.siblings().first().next().children();
      eSlideCur = eSlide.siblings().first().children().add(eSlide.children());
    };
    eSlideCur.stop().css('opacity', 0).delay(350).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    eSlidePrev.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
  }
```

I think you can use onSlideBefore()